# Percentage based padding is breaking my layout

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage

I'm attempting to convert all widths and margin and padding to percentages to make the site I'm working on responsive. I got as far as the headder w/o issue but now I'm stuck.

When I change the padding on my li items the layout breaks. On the full site the padding should be 6px but even when I set the padding to a percentage, even as small as 0.1%, it bumps one of the elements down. The site isn't live but I'm including a couple of screenshots and some code. Any ideas?

```
aside#footer-brands ul  {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

aside#footer-brands ul li {
padding:6px;
float:left;
list-style: none;   
}

aside#footer-brands ul li a {
background-image: url(/images/csr/footer/brands/sprite-brands.png);
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
display: block;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}

<aside id="footer-brands">
            <h6>Our Brands</h6>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="keurig-logo" href="http://www.keurig.com">Keurig</a></li>
                <li><a class="gmcr-logo" href="http://www.greenmountaincoffee.com">Green Mountain Coffee</a></li>
                <li><a class="tullys-logo" href="http://www.tullys.com">Tullys</a></li>
                <li><a class="timothys-logo" href="http://www.timothys.com">Timothys</a></li>
                <li><a class="diedrich-logo" href="http://www.diedrich.com">Diedrich</a></li>
                <li><a class="vanhoutte-logo" href="http://www.keurig.com/shop/k-cups/all-k-cups?hdnCategoryFacets=Brand:Van%20Houtte&hdnBaseFacets=Brand">Van Houtte</a></li>
            </ul>
</aside>
```

First questions so I can't post images but here's [how it should look](https://img.skitch.com/20120514-ng553b28ana6khsss619cag72e.jpg)...

[image: https://img.skitch.com/20120514-ng553b28ana6khsss619cag72e.jpg]

and how it looks [when I changed the padding to a percent](https://img.skitch.com/20120514-j94cgs2g8dppktcacbns3jmig2.jpg)...

[image: https://img.skitch.com/20120514-j94cgs2g8dppktcacbns3jmig2.jpg]

Edited to add URL:

You can view the page at http://nightowlsrock.com/3-col.html

Comment: All browsers or just one in particular?  Can you construct a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: Also, you haven't posted all your CSS. In your example, your `<a>`s all have the same width.

Comment: @Mr-Lister, each '<a>' has a set width right now based on the image size. Responsive images are next on the list.

Comment: @Sparky672 I checked with my work to make sure I could post the page publicly which will be way easier. You can see the page here [http://nightowlsrock.com/3-col.html](http://nightowlsrock.com/3-col.html). I looked at the page with the 6px converted to 1.083% and the layout was broken in Safari, FF and Chrome. The CSS that's giving me trouble is on line 701.

Comment: Emily, the URL will be helpful but a URL or a demo should augment, not substitute, information in the question.  We like the questions and answers to be as _self-contained_ as possible.  I rolled it back _and then_ added your URL.

Comment: @Sparky672 thanks. I couldn't include all the information because !'m too new and had a 2 URL limit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: ignore what I said before.

The [W3C page on padding](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) says

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

And yes, undefined behaviour is what you see. I could produce vastly different results by setting the value to `.8%`, `1%`, `1.2%` etc.
So the answer seems to be that you should set the UL to some predetermined width first.

Comment: I edited the width on the containing aside, set the width on the 'ul' to '100%' and changed the padding on the 'li' to a slightly thicker 'padding-right'. It seems to have fixed the issue but I still have some additional browser testing to do.

Comment: Yes I just set the width of containter, in this case ul to 100%, and it works with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS3 flexbox? It doesn't require any percentages (just proportions and the browser natively handles the widths). It also ensures things are always on the same line (no bumping down like with floats).

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

As for padding specifically, I think most browsers have issues with widths less than 1px so if you want things to be "pixel-perfect", you may have to use fixed pixel widths with media queries to achieve this. But I've found that you can usually get things "close enough" with flexbox.